# Express.js sessions reset at server restart

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, restart

I am using the express-session package with a custom MongoDB based session store, but for some reason the sessions are deleted everytime I stop and re-run the script.

From looking at the database I can see that the sessions are saved.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use connect-mongo (https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) for storing sessions in database so that it would persist even after restarting the node server.

Here is an example on how you can use it. Example is from its **Readme**.

```
var session    = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret: settings.cookie_secret,
    store: new MongoStore({
      db : settings.db,
    })
  }));
```

Comment: I would also suggest [connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis) for storing into redis.